# Is it good practice to package an SQL database inside a JAR?

Tags: java, jar

I would like to create a Java library without any dependency, but it needs to use an embedded SQL database. Is it good practice to package both the binary database file and the driver to access it inside the JAR file? What are some advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go on, it's a widely adopted practice used by Hibernate for example.

**For a memory constrained devices:**

Then do not use embedded database at all. Try using [ThoughtWorks](http://www.thoughtworks.com/) library [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) which serializes/deserializes objects to XML/jSon which can be stored in files. Very effective solution with a small memory foot print.

Comment: The reason for which I need a database is because I need to search for records (`SELECT description FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%...%'` kind of queries). Does XStream provide such functionality? Or is there any memory efficient solution for this, even if not SQL?

Comment: No it doesn't provide such functionality.

Answer (score 4):

[HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)

More and more Java applications have their own 'in-memory' database that is launched upon application start. Check out hsqldb for an example.
Most obvious advantage is that you control the database and don't have to take different DB servers and their sql dialects into account.

Answer (score 0):

Your database will be read-only (since you cant repackage the jar at runtime). If that is fine then go nuts :)